# Can I use symfony 1.4 propel forms and form filters along with builders in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to use sf1 forms instead of sf2, because sf1 forms and form filters (propel) are what is being used among my colleagues and sf2 forms we believe lack what we require.

Is there any particular easy way out that I am missing rather than trying to borrow symfony 1.4 specific codes to a symfony 2 bundle?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? sf1 & sf2 are completely different and it will hard to mix them the way you want to do ..

Comment: I don't want to mix them, I want to use sf1 forms instead of sf2, because sf1 forms and form filters (propel) are what is being used among  my colleagues and sf2 forms we believe lack what we require.

Answer (score 0):

Filters in symfony 1.4 are almost the same as forms except for:

- It can store values in session
- It can build query by its values

You can implement it easily by your self, and even create useful bundle for other people.